# Mini-games development like Wario Ware in Unity

Tags: unity, architecture

I'm trying to develop a game that consists of multiple simple minigames, just like Wario Ware or Dumb Ways to Die, but in Unity. The problem is I'm not sure how the project should be structured. I've been reading about it and so far I have encountered 3 options:

1. Make multiple scenes, one for each minigame and load/unload each of them when necessary.
2. Have all minigames loaded in the same scene, each with their own canvas.
3. Make the minigames within the UI.

It seems that there isn't a lot of information about developing a collection of minigames as a game. I'm not able to find a single tutorial or course about it.

Comment: All of these sound like viable options. Which have you tried so far, and what issue have you encountered with it that we can help you overcome?

Comment: It would as well depend a bit of the type of your minigame, how you want to connect them to each other, how many you have in total. Just start with two of them and see what works the best for you